# IIS 6 file upload limit

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have a requirement to allow 30 mb of file upload via my web application.

It works fine till around 29 mb of data. But fails as soon as file size reaches 29.1 mb. I get 404 error.

In my web.config, I have given 
`<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="30720">` which is (30*1024)

Still it fails.

Am I missing something else?

IIS 6 server on a windows 2003 server

Something can be done at IIS level ?

Comment: have you tried seting maximum content length to wide values? i.e.
           MaxRequestLength="1048576"      (1GB)

Comment: Thanks  Emanuele Greco for the response. I can give a wide value but don't wanna go far beyond the actual limit. Just thinking if there is a way to get somewhere around 30 MB.

Comment: Yes, i understand: I'ma saying that if with  MaxRequestLength="1048576" you can upload 30Mb files, you have found the solution: just have to decrease MaxRequestLength until it stops working with that file.

Comment: OK, wanted to avoid hit and trial. 
But this seems to be the best possible solution so far. I will give it a shot and will update if I get something better.

Comment: give at least 1 try..  40960 KB (40 MB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have set the limit to 30*1024 kiB exactly? And you are trying to upload a 30 MiB file?

What limit is it that you have set? Is it the limit for the total size of the request? Then you need to add a couple of kiB to ensure that all headers can fit. Also, uploaded files are subject to encoding, so you don't know that a 30 MiB file doesn't transfer as much more...

Comment: Thanks atornblad for the reply. Yes I was looking for exact 30 MB of file to be uploaded.
Although got your point here. Need to consider extra KBs of headers as well as consider encoding.
Is there a  way to know how much extra space these two count can count for?

Comment: There is a way. Measure it. Upload large files from a few different browsers on different networks and raise/lower the limit until you reach the desired results. Don't forget to add some extra room for unexpected stuff.

Comment: ...or just look at the network traffic using some free tool.

Comment: Emanuele Greco's answer was more or less same. Although atornblad provided me where were the gaps were in my calculation.
I am using limit as 31 MB now. I am able to upload the original file mentioned in the question plus few other files.
Thanks for your help guys.